# Scraping tables from multiple weblinks

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping

I am a beginner in python and as a part of a project wanted to extract tables containing CIK and company name from multiple links like this.

[image]

I need to modify this code such that instead of processing one link at a time, I should be able to extract the given table of all the present links.

P.S. we have to read the multiple links present in CSV and extract the output for each links again in the same CSV

Sample Link: https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&SIC=4911&owner=include&match=&start=100&count=100&hidefilings=0

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgaraction=getcompany&SIC=4911&owner=include&match=&start=100&count=100&hidefilings=0'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
print(df)
df.to_csv('delete.csv')
```

Comment: not sure if scrapping from sec.gov  is a good idea as start. However the side is composed by divs. it will be difficult to get tables from it. You could look for beatiful soap and than search for ID tableFile2. maybe first you look in a browser for the tags...

Comment: Can't we make a function and call the function for all the links and append all the outputs together?

Comment: Yes you can do that with BeautifulSoup.find_all('tr') under your tableFile2. but that has a steel learning curve. You cant't do that with pandas directly..thought

Comment: I didn't understand properly. Could you please provide code for that? That will be really grateful.

Comment: PI look here for find all. That side has some explanations too. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/web-scraping-with-beautiful-soup